# D3js zoom on Line Chart

Tags: d3.js, graph, zooming

I built a graph like this one: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245
(using d3js)
But I would like to zoom into the graph with the mouse.
I tried a lot of things that i saw on others examples, on youtube or here, but nothing to do (it didn't works) i guess i'm just bad !

Thank you for your help.
(Sorry my english isn't perfect)

Comment: please post some code of what you have already tried

Comment: https://codepen.io/brantwills/pen/igsoc